# Выезжающая панель сдвигает основной экран

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день!

Есть следующая задача:

Необходимо, чтобы по клику на ссылку, слева или справа страницы выезжал блок с минимальной высотой `100%` и шириной (к примеру) `200px` и при этом сдвигался основной экран.

Самое интересное то, что изначально, основной экран резиновый - `width: 100%`;

Реально ли реализовать подобную задачу?

Comment: Уважаемые @eicto и @Bars, а что если при отлове события click, ширину экрана делать не 100%; а приравнивать к $(window).width(). 

Соответственно получим размер в пиксялях (фиксированный).

И еще, возможно ли сделать, чтобы закрывались эти панели жестом - drag and drop?

Comment: ну у меня вроде и так фиксировано все, а закрывать... ну повесте события, у меня просто нет смартфона под рукой. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2wMdN/2/

Comment: Эх, знал бы я как его повесить - обязательно бы повесил!:)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2wMdN/3/

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо.

Comment: > если при отлове события click, ширину экрана делать не 100%; а приравнивать к $(window).width().

Тогда теряется смысл 100% в плане резиновости, нет? Костылек получается.

Comment: Возможно, но ведь резиновость теряется только на время появления и присутствия на экране нового блока, а затем возвращается резиновость ... Нет?

Comment: Это если ты сам эту резиновость вернешь :) Кроме того, как насчет такого варианта: показал сайдбар, а потом изменил размер браузера/перевернул телефон из портретной ориентации в альбомную? В моем же примере об этом заботится сам браузер.

Answer (score 3):

А я бы сделал вот так:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2wMdN/

Идея в следующем - сделать блок шире экрана, и скроллить его.

CSS:

```
wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.left-border, .right-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.left-border {
    left: 0;
}
.right-border {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -200px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left-border">Left</div>
    <div class="content">content
        <br /> <a class="show-left" href="#left">Show left</a>

        <br /> <a class="show-right" href="#right">Show right</a> 
        <br /> <a class="hide-borders" href="#right">hide them</a>

    </div>
    <div class="right-border">Right</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $wrap = $('.wrap').show().scrollLeft(100);
$('.show-left').click(function () {
    $wrap.animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
    }, 200);
});
$('.show-right').click(function () {
    $wrap.animate({
        scrollLeft: 200
    }, 200);
});
$('.hide-borders,.right-border,.left-border').click(function () {
    $wrap.animate({
        scrollLeft: 100
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: там проблема с вертикальной прокруткой, но можно решить, например сдвигая боковые элементы на позицию прокрутки с помощью js.

Comment: Нет, это не вариант ... Это делается для мобильных - будет глючить

Comment: почему будет глючить ?

Comment: Был опыт, когда блоку с абсолютной позицией задавал задавал top относительно scrollTop - все скокало...

Comment: а с боковой панелью ? ну можно ее размер просто подогнать к размеру блока контента, это к вопросу не относится особо, там в зависимости от желания делать надо, ну и ещё вопрос почему у вас скакало.

Answer (score 2):

При таких состыковках относительных и абсолютных величин я нахожу только одно решение: таблица.

[Вот как-то так я бы сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/3zn2b/).

Comment: @Bars, стоит задача, чтобы основной экран именно сдвигался ...

Comment: А, ми скузи, не понял этого.